# Вывод Reply кнопки и блокировка клавиатуры

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

При старте телеграм бота по команде /start выводится Reply кнопка, при этом необходимо заблокировать возможность пользователя что-то ввести в поле для ввода. Как это поле скрыть либо заблокировать функционал клавиатуры?

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/0r57wT_edGilPw

Функция вывода кнопки

```
def sogl_keyboard():
    sogl_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    sogl_check = types.KeyboardButton('✅ Даю согласие на обработку персональных данных')
    sogl_keyboard.add(sogl_check)
    return sogl_keyboard
```

Comment: В такой реализации после /start поле с кнопкой появляется и исчезает почти моментально, и остается поле для ввода

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что это возможно, где ты видел в Телеге чтобы если ты заходишь в чат и у тебя там нету доступа к полю чтобы написать сообщение?

Суть бота - чтобы человек смог текстом либо кнопками взаимодействовать с ботом и какая-то программа это все отрабатывала и возвращала ответ.

Как по мне это лучше сделать inline кнопкой, если ты боишься что юзер что-то сломает (либо реплай кнопкой и проверять текст, если текст нужный - значит человек согласен, если не тот - значит так и напиши что человек должен принять условия)

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы скрыть поле ввода вы можете использовать `reply_markup` параметр в `send_message` методе:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я соглашаюсь на обработку данных', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Но в вашем варианте надо добавить просто еще один параметр:

```
sogl_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
```

Вместо вашего:

```
sogl_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
```

Все вместе:

```
def sogl_keyboard():
    sogl_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    sogl_check = types.KeyboardButton('✅ Даю согласие на обработку персональных данных')
    sogl_keyboard.add(sogl_check)
    return sogl_keyboard
```

Comment: При такой реализации поле с кнопкой полявляется и счезает сразу же, а поле ввода остается

[ссылка]https://t.me/vlad_filatov_bot

Comment: а первый метод пробывали?

Comment: Я скопировал функцию которую вы написали + строку

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я соглашаюсь на обработку данных', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда оставьте свою функцию, удалите bot.send и замените переменную sogl_check на sogl_check = types.KeyboardButton('✅ Даю согласие на обработку персональных данных', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()) и пробуйте. Я бы с радостью помог более быстро, был бы у меня сейчас доступ к моему телеграм аккаунту

Comment: Всё равно выводится окно для ввода.